# How to Customize datetime ticks in Plotly (Python)

Tags: python, plotly-dash, gantt-chart, xticks

so I've created a gantt chart with Plotly's Dash and I'd be quite happy, if it weren't for the x axis ticks.

Here's my chart:

[image]

Nice, but for the x axis ticks. I’d like to customize them to fit my needs:

1. I’d like them to start on a monday (04 Jan), instead of a sunday (10 Jan) and continue week-wise as they already do
2. Instead of “04 Jan”, the tick labels should be something like this: “KW: 01 ('21)”. Here, KW is supposed to mean calendar week.
3. I don’t want to show every tick label. It’d be nice if the chart only shows every first KW of a year and every fifth

So, I was looking for a way to do this and found in [Plotly Layout References (xaxis-tickvals)](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickvals) that there’s supposed to be a smooth way to do so. I just need a list of tickvals for the locations in the chart and a list of ticktext for the labels and need to set tickmode to ‘array’.

As my code is too long, I’ll just provide a little example. Let’s say this is my code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import datetime

df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2021-01-08', Finish='2021-01-29'),
  dict(Task="Job B", Start='2021-01-15', Finish='2021-02-12'),
  dict(Task="Job C", Start='2021-01-29', Finish='2021-02-19'),
  dict(Task="Job D", Start='2021-02-05', Finish='2021-02-26')]

my_figure = ff.create_gantt(df, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
weeks_ticktext = ['KW: 01 (\'21)', '', '', '', 'KW: 05 (\'21)', '', '', '', '']
weeks_tickvals = [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 11, 0, 0),
          datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 25, 0, 0),
          datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 8, 0, 0),
          datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 22, 0, 0),
          datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
my_figure.layout.xaxis['tickmode'] = 'array'
my_figure.layout.xaxis['tickvals'] = weeks_tickvals
my_figure.layout.xaxis['ticktext'] = weeks_ticktext
my_figure.show()
```

Then, this code will produce the following graph:

[image]

Now, I don’t understand why the x axis didn’t start and didn’t get displayed the way I wanted them to be.

I also asked the same question in the [Dash Community](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-customize-datetime-ticks-in-plotly-python/37835), but didn't get no help so far.

I am thankful for any comment!

Answer (score 1):

1) To set the start date you can adjust the axis range with something like

```
my_figure.layout['xaxis'].update(range=[min, max])
```

where you have to figure out how to find min and max of your labels.

2) As documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#using-tickformat-atttribute--datetime) the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is to set the xaxis_tickformat in the layout. Try adding the line

```
my_figure.layout['xaxis_tickformat'] = '%d %B whatever <br>%Y'
```

just before the last line and play with the format string as explained and documented [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md)

3) Probably all this customization will lead you to write a simple function that returns lists of strings to use as ticks. If you want to stick with the datetime objects you could check [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/date-tick-formatting/11081/3) post (with no solution) as an entry point for your search.

Good coding!